# python cannot decode circumflex

Tags: python, unicode

```
data = [item for item in contents.encode('utf-8').split('\r\n')]
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1807: ordinal not in range(128)

Why can't it encode it when I encode it?

Comment: It says it can't *decode* it.  What is `contents`?  If it's a byte string, you need to use `decode` to convert it to unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using Python 2.  `.encode` can only encode Unicode strings.  If you try to `.encode` a byte string, Python 2 will implicitly try to `.decode` the byte string to Unicode, using the default `ascii` codec, before using the explicit `.encode('utf-8')`.

`contents` is already a byte string.  If that byte string is encoded in UTF-8, use `.decode('utf-8')` instead to convert it to a Unicode string.